# identifierForVendor for iOS6 or later. What about identifying iOS5 or earlier devices from the same app?

Tags: ios, uidevice

I needed a unique ID for each device which uses an app built in Xcode 6.1 (iOS 8.1).

I have used `identifierForVendor` for devices with iOS 6 or later. However the app is also meant to support iOS 5 or earlier devices. So what I did is

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
   return [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
}
else{
   return [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:@selector(uniqueIdentifier)];
}
```

But some of the posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16602909/3336675) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12506893/3336675) say that it would be rejected by Apple if `uniqueIdentifier` method is called.

If that is the case, then can someone please guide me how to do this?

Thanks.